# Estar harto/quemado/agotado de algo - differences (if any)

Tags: vocabulario

I would like to ask whether there are any differences in meaning between the following three phrases:

- estar harto de algo
- estar quemado de algo
- estar agotado de algo.

Comment: I would ordered them from less irritated to more irritated as: (1)`estar agotado de algo` (2)`estar harto de algo` (3)`estar quemado de algo`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At least in my environment (Argentina):

- estar harto de algo
- estar agotado de algo

are similar, and in some cases can be interchangeable, but

- estar harto

is more akin to "I'm fed up with", "I cannot stand that anymore". While

- estar agotado

is primarily equivalent to "be very tired". This is more used when one is tired because of some work one have done, while one can "estar harto" of things that one must bear. Further, "estar harto" suggest disgust, while the second is more neutral, one can "estar agotado" from doing something pleasant (say gym).

Regarding "quemado", in my experience that's a more informal (almost slang) word, used for stressful  (not merely physical, nor anecdotical) situations, and it's used predominantly without a complement. "Estoy quemado" = "I'm seriously worn out".

Comment: Thanks for a thorough description. What I wonder now is whether European practice is similar or not.

Comment: @MadHatter the use described by leonbloy is based in the actual meaning of the words "harto and "agotado". Since "quemado" is slang, it may vary according to location. In any case, what leonbloy wrote is correct from a Spanish (as a language) point of view, because that is what the word "harto" and "agotado" mean. In an informal conversation you could always say something meaning something else but that happens in all languages and locations.